# How to structure model in realm database & is it ok that I use Date as a primaryKey?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to create a realm database that stores some data every day. I hope I describe this right, I didn't work with realm in a long time. I can also provide the code that I have so far, but it's not much.

The end result is that when I get the data from the database I see the data for the last month(so probably make the sum for every day of the last month), same for the month before that and the one before, etc. (I added a image how it should look for a month)

[image]

My question is how should I create the model?

My idea so far for a `day`:

`date` -> primaryKey

`data` -> Int/String

But could I somehow also store it by month in the database so that I don't have to make the sum every time? Like an array/dictionary with all the days for a month. So could I add a field that would be something like this when a month is over? Or create another model that has an array of `day`?

months -> [`day`] ?

Also, can I/is it ok that I use `Date` as a primaryKey? (I know that realm's primary key is `String`, but I could convert the `Date` to `String`)

Anything would help. I really don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the date as a primary key. Primary key values should be unique, dates are not necessarily unique. Unlikely that two tasks will occur at exactly the same time, but not impossible. A `UUID` (`UUID().uuidString`) may suit your needs for this better. The chance of a UUID collision is unbelievably small.

As far as not wanting to do the calculations, are you having to retrieve the month totals frequently? If not, it might not be a big performance hit to just fetch all objects matching the month and doing the calculation on them. I would probably try this route first and if it isn't performant enough, look for alternative solutions.

Another option would be to create a Month object. Each data point gets associated with a month object. That month object can add the day's data to the total when added and store it to the database. That way you can query the month object to determine the sum. This has issues of you needing to keep that sum in sync and adds more data to your database that can be determined by other means.

Your question is very general so I can't give much in the way of a specific answer.